# Ajax Control Toolkit Date Picker - Is it possible to not have to select the day?

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender

So I can set the date format on the Calendar Extender to it displays just the month, but you would still have to select the Year, then the Month, then the Day.

I would like to just select the Year, then the Month.

```
    <cc2:CalendarExtender ID="DateOfReleaseCalendarExtender" runat="server"
        TargetControlID="DateOfReleaseTextBox"
      Format="MMMM yyyy" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a built-in feature, no. You'll have to extend it yourself. I would probably hook into the Javascript events--whichever one you think makes sense in your situation.

Comment: The alterantive is to use jQueryUI DatePicker check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only

Answer (score 3):

This requires patching the CalendarExtender part of the AjaxControlToolkit assembly.

I found a blog post that explains how to do something very similar to what you are trying to do: 
**[Patching the CalendarExtender Control](http://tonesdotnetblog.wordpress.com/2009/04/15/how-to-patch-the-ajax-control-toolkit-calendarextender-to-add-decade-support-and-initialview-part-1/)**