# AJAX Calendar extender select month and year

Tags: asp.net, ajax, calendar

Is it real and how can I think about it.

To make so the user will select only the month and year, not date, because he need a period on full month, not some date.

here is simple control ...

```
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" />
                        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox3_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                            Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox3" />
```

but Calendar selects the day ... I need select the month.

how ?

Comment: Calendar selects the day ... I need select the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing calendar extender in the AjaxControlToolkit does not select the month.  Maybe the JQuery date picker, but I don't know that it necessarily does.

You could have them select a day, and derive the month/year...  I know that's a bit of a hack, but haven't seen too much dealing with month year, except for providing two drop downs and having them select it.

Comment: yes ... I think I need to make this two drop down ^_ It isn't hard so I guess

Comment: You can use the JQuery UI calendar, check tha answer by Ben Koehler at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only

Answer (score 2):

There is a 'Format' property in the control. You can try setting it as [MMMM, yyyy]

```
<ajaxToolkit:Calendar runat="server"
TargetControlID="Date1"
CssClass="ClassName"
**Format="MMMM d, yyyy"**
PopupButtonID="Image1" />
```