# How to use only part of the Ajax Toolkit's calendar extender control

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender

I currently have two requirements of the AJAX Calendar Extender, one simple and one complex. 
I would like to solve the simple scenario, and if the complex scenario can't be feasibly solved, then the workaround that I have is acceptable.

**Simple Scenario:**
I really only want to show the Year/Month Selector of the calendar control

1. When the user first clicks the associated textbox, I want to show the grid of years.
2. When the user then clicks a year, I want to show the grid of months.
3. When the user clicks the month, I want to fill two text boxes with the start and end dates of the selected month.

I really like the look of the AJAX calendar extender, but I don't want them to be able to select the day or for the day selection portion of the control to be displayed.
Is there any way to enable this scenario?

***Note**:*I have found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408377/ajax-calendar-extender-select-month-and-year) like this which was not worded the way I want, and it would not have been considered proper etiquette for me to piggy-back onto that question, so on the [advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64496/what-is-the-protocol-with-regard-to-piggybacking-questions) of the meta community, I have decided to re-phrase this*

**Complicated Scenario**:
If the above is solved, I would like a different control to allow the user to select a year and a Quarter, and have the start and end dates be populated with the Selected Quarter start and End dates.