# need easy to use date selection menu, for just date / year

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need a jQuery date picker that asks the user to select month and year.

I want it to be simple and not confusing at all. I could use two drop-down menus, one for month, the other for year, but I want it to be dead simple, just the click of the menue.

I prefer it to be jQuery, anyone know of an elegant choice in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see a previous solution

[jQuery UI DatePicker to show month year only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-date-picker-to-show-month-year-only)

Do not miss these two parts out (like me)

```
<style>
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
    }
</style>
```

and the following in the datepicker function:

```
changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [a plugin](http://www.ajaxline.com/10-best-jquery-datepickers-plugins) that someone else has put the effort into designing. I just googled it and came up with quite a few.