# Set today's date as default date in jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I just want today's date  to be the default value in the input that is using jQuery UI's `datepicker`:

```
<input id="mydate" type="text" />
```

I tried the below code but it didn't work:

```
var currentDate = new Date();  
$("#mydate").datepicker("setDate",currentDate);
```

Answer (score 116):

You need to make the call to setDate separately from the initialization call. So to create the datepicker and set the date in one go:

```
$("#mydate").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Why it is like this I do not know. If anyone did, that would be interesting information.

Answer (score 90):

You have to initialize the [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) before calling a [datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/datepicker/) [method](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/datepicker/#methods).

```js
$("#mydate").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
//-initialization--^          ^-- method invokation
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="mydate" />
```

---

Here is a [**Working JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/f2md3zy5/1/).

<sub>P.S: This assumes that you have the correct date set in your computer</sub>

Comment: Thanks! you could also add to your example datepicker("selectedDate", new Date()); which is selecting the date only when the OP opens the calendar.

Comment: @Revious Actually, I couldn't find any reference to such method... There's also [`defaultDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate), but it won't set the date inside the textbox which is being asked in question...

Answer (score 33):

Its very simple you just add this script,

```
$("#mydate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Here, setDate set today date & dateFormat define which format you want set or show.

Hope its simple script work..

Answer (score 7):

```
$("#date").datepicker.regional[""].dateFormat = 'dd/mm/yy';
$("#date").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Always work for me

Answer (score 4):

This one work for me , first you bind datepicker to text-box and in next line set (today as default date) the date to it

```
$("#date").datepicker();

$("#date").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Answer (score 4):

Note: When you pass setDate, you are calling a method which assumes the datepicker has already been initialized on that object.

```
$(function() {    
   $('#date').datepicker();
   $('#date').datepicker('setDate', '04/23/2014');
});
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/wimarbueno/hQkec/1/

Answer (score 4):

Set default date in initialization:

```
$("#date").datepicker({
    defaultDate: '01/26/2014'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me and also localised it:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
$(function() {
   $( "#txtDespatchDate" ).datepicker( );
   $( "#txtDespatchDate" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy" );
   $('#txtDespatchDate').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set minDate: 0

Here is my script:

```
$("#valid_from")
   .datepicker({
     minDate: 0,
     defaultDate: "+1w",
     changeMonth: true,
     numberOfMonths: 3
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried many ways and came up with my own solution which works absolutely as required.

"mydate" is the ID of input or datepicker element/control.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        var dateNewFormat, onlyDate, today = new Date();

        dateNewFormat = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1);

        onlyDate = today.getDate();

        if (onlyDate.toString().length == 2) {
            dateNewFormat += '-' + onlyDate;
        }
        else {
            dateNewFormat += '-0' + onlyDate;
        }
        $('#mydate').val(dateNewFormat);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined

```
$("#mydate").datepicker({});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('update', new Date(year,month,day));
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$("#mydate").datepicker("setDate",'1d');
```

Comment: What's `1d` supposed to be?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, `1d` means `today`.