# How make default current date in selectable in jquery date picker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Here i am doing disabled the except the current week dates.it is working fine also bit here i am facing one problem

> Here i want to do default current date is selectable  , how can do this ?

```
$(function () {
$(".bhj").datepicker({
    //In Datepicker set the Calendar display start with Monday
    firstDay: 1,
    //Before Populating the Calendar set the Enabled & Disabled Dates using beforeShowDay(Date) function
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        //var monday = new Date("June 1, 2013 00:00:00");
        //Get today's date
        var monday = new Date();
        //Set the time of today's date to 00:00:00 
        monday.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        //alert(monday.getDay() + ' : ' + monday.getDate() + ' : ' + (monday.getDay() || 7) + ' : ' + monday);
        /*
        Below Line sets the Date to Monday (Start of that Week)
        (monday.getDay() || 7) returns the value of getDay() 
        ie., [ 1 - Mon, 2 - Tue, 3 - Wed, 4 - Thu, 5 - Fri, 6 - Sat ]  
        except for Sunday where it returns 7. 
        The return value is used to calculate the Date of that Week's Monday
        */
        monday.setDate(monday.getDate() + 1 - (monday.getDay() || 7));
        //Set the Date to Monday
        var sunday = new Date(monday);
        //Now add 6 to Monday to get the Date of Sunday (End of that Week)
        sunday.setDate(monday.getDate() + 5);
        //Now return the enabled and disabled dates to datepicker
        return [(date >= monday && date <= sunday), ''];
    }
});
//Set the date format to dd/mm/yy ie., 30/10/1989
$(".bhj").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
});
```

Comment: What you want? only enable current week and disable rest of the dates?

Comment: Possibly duplicate. Try this link [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915990/set-todays-date-as-default-date-in-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( ".bhj" ).datepicker({dateFormat:"yy/mm/dd"}).datepicker("setDate",new Date());
```

you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand, but I think you mean that you want the datepicker to default on today? FYI, [there is documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/), just view all examples.

```
$(".bhj").datepicker();
$(".bhj").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Or if you want it to select from today onwards (so not going back in time):

```
$(".bhj").datepicker();
$(".bhj").datepicker("minDate ", 0); // or -1 for yesterday, or +1 for tomorrow etc
```

Or if you want only weekdays ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9295262/2519416)):

```
$( ".datepicker.future").datepicker('option','beforeShowDay',function(date){
    var td = date.getDay();
    var ret = [(date.getDay() != 0 && date.getDay() != 6),'',(td != 'Sat' && td != 'Sun')?'':'only on workday'];
    return ret;
});
```