# calendar with months and years without dates

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I need a calendar that shows only the months and years without the dates, because I am developing a web project for bus agencies, and it will have an option to show for every month for every agent how many tickets he sold and how much money he made! somehow like google adsense calendar where you pick the time or period. I am using an already made calendar but its with dates,months,years. Maybe there is a change to modify it to show only months and years but I am not good with javascripting at all! this is it:

```
http://www.softcomplex.com/products/tigra_calendar/docs/
```

My question is what would you recommend me to use or to do? is there any better way or tutorial to make this type of calendar or an already made calendar?

**THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME AND HELP.**

Comment: So, you're just looking for a list of `year - month` strings?

Comment: yeah some think like that but I guess more advanced with the style, to look like the calendar I am using would be great! I guess!

Comment: if you are not good with javascript, i recommend using [Jquery](http://www.jquery.com) , the date picker plugin will take care of the calender for you. but you still have to learn javasccript to write efficient code

Comment: Someone asked kinda similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-date-picker-to-show-month-year-only

Comment: @ Ibu, yes you are right I have to learn javascript but somehow I dont find it interesting and I dont have really much time for it!

Comment: since it's not that interesting you shouldnt ask a question about it, and just find someone else to code for you

Comment: I'm not actually sure how you'd do a *stylish calendar* without *days*… :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you just  add loop for year and month drop down box (select option list), as you dont need date.That is the simplest way.

```
var year=1950
<select name='year'> 
fo(i=year;i<2012:i++)
{
 <option value=i>i</option
}
</select>


var month=1
<select name='month'> 
fo(i=month;i<=12:i++)
{
 <option value=i>i</option
}
</select>
```

you can do this in php loop and js validate or only js itself .your wish

Comment: Thank you very much zod this is exactly what I did ;)