# Jquery datepicker - only day and month

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want the user to specify their birthday or anniversary date (without year) in a form. For this, I want to use jquery datepicker but it should not show any year option at all. How to do it?

I tried modifying the code in [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-date-picker-to-show-month-year-only) by making `changeDay: true` and `changeYear: false` but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

set the css to hide the year and the dateFormat as K6t said

```
.ui-datepicker-year{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: how can i distinguish this certain date-picker, when there are other datepickers too?

Comment: For cartain datepickers you can use it inside .focus,  see this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41931400/3412696

Comment: Not suggested, use config instead see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6799216/5277245

Answer (score 14):

You could do:

```
$('#date').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd MM'
    });
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u8GnD/1/

Comment: this does not work. the year does not change when a future date is selected.

Comment: your today button is not working how to make it work

Comment: Make sure to change the attribute of the html input to readonly, otherwise you can still change the input value manually.

Answer (score 7):

You can hide year from a datepicker like this :

```
$(".daypicker").datepicker( { 
    changeYear: false, 
    dateFormat: 'MM-dd',
}).focus(function () {
    $(".ui-datepicker-year").hide();
});
```

It wont affect to other datepickers in same page.

Comment: This works will with .on() and .off() to make it temporarilly hiddable

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
format: "dd-MM",
viewMode: "months", 
maxViewMode: "months"
});
```

this will surely hide year from datepicker view, will show **only month and days** panel

Comment: These don't seem to be valid params for the jQuery UI datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( function() {
     var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true, 
        changeYear: false}).val();
});
```

Comment: Always add explanation to your answer. Mere code does not help.

Comment: This answer might or might not solve the issue the OP experience, so please always add an explanation to you answer to clarify how it might fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I may be late on the show but I found all of the above answers/suggestions and comments to be almost correct but someone might miss the correct jquery plugin to make the code work.

Someone struggling to make it done pls consider changing your javascript plugins first, and use the following instead

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

change dateFormat as

```
dateFormat: 'dd MM',
```

in datePicker.js file

Comment: Don't edit the datepicker code if you can just use the options.