# jQuery UI DatePicker to select only day and month

Tags: jquery, datepicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery datepicker - only day and month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799092/jquery-datepicker-only-day-and-month)

I'm using Jquery datepicker on my new website, but I need to select only day and month...

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm-dd" });
```