# AngularUI Datepicker day and month ONLY

Tags: javascript, css, datepicker, angular-ui

I've seen answers concerning [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799092/jquery-datepicker-only-day-and-month) but not angular ui. I would like to display only days and months. I've found [this](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=component&format=&weekStart=&startDate=1.1.2014&endDate=31.12.2014&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=fr&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) and can set a min date (1.1.2014) and max date (31.12.2014) but in the picker I still see the year beside the month and if I click on the year, I get a not relevant view.

Comment: no option to do this at the moment, they were just talking about it a few months ago https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1993

Comment: Seems I'll need to wait few more months...