# Css date picker without year

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can anyone help me finding me a calender without year.I have found one.But problem is after choosing date and month, in input box year is showing.I want only day and month in input box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery datepicker - only day and month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799092/jquery-datepicker-only-day-and-month)

Comment: Are you using jquery datepicker?

Comment: Yes.I am using Jquery datepicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Jquery Datepicker, you will have to do it like this:

html:

```
<input type='text' id='datepicker'>
```

javascript (JQuery):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker( { changeYear: false, dateFormat: 'dd-mm' } );
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7j31vnm/) (see needed external resources)