# How to show only years in the view of datepicker?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

when I click on `textbox` of date then `datepicker` will be open and it has year, month, and date view.

I just wanted year view to be shown that I could only select year not the month and date.

I am using `bootstrap datepicker`.

my code

```
<input type='text'
      class='form-control white-bg pointer-cursor'
      id="holiday_year"
      datepicker-popup=' yyyy'
      datepicker-month=hide
      ng-model='weekly_holiday.holiday_year'
      is-open='$holiday_year_open'
      ng-click='$holiday_year_open=true'
      ng-readonly='true'
      date-validator/>
```

tell me addition to this and what I want to do in controller.

Comment: share code link if u have like plunker, JS fiddle

Comment: There's another thread with similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799092/jquery-datepicker-only-day-and-month

Answer (score 1):

to select only year you can use:

```
$(function() { 
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy' });
});
```

main source of demo:[here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-datepicker-only-month-or-year)

**EDIT:** *to display only year:*

```js
$(function() {
    $('.date-picker-year').datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, 1));
        }
    });
 $(".date-picker-year").focus(function () {
        $(".ui-datepicker-month").hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-calendar { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<input type="text" name="txtFromYear" id="txtYear" class="date-picker-year"/>
```

Comment: yeah i retrieve only year, but i am asking about the view of datepicker, that  when i click on textbox then only year has to show directly

Comment: it shows all year , month and day view.    i edit question with my datepicker, tell me modification in that one @SuchitKumar

Comment: try  adding this css `.ui-datepicker-calendar { display: none; } `

Answer (score 0):

for future devs:

```
          $(x).datepicker({
                format: 'yyyy',
                todayHighlight: true,
                autoclose: true,
                minViewMode: 2
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The following options worked for me: yearFirst and startView 2 for year (0 is day, 1 is month):

```
        $('input#year').datepicker({
            yearFirst: true,
            startView: 2,
            format: 'yyyy',
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoHide: true,
            pick: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).val($(this).datepicker('getDate', true));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#holiday_year").datepicker( {
    format: "yyyy",
    viewMode: "years", 
    minViewMode: "years"
});
```