# Can Datepicker be used as a month Calendar picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

I wonder if it is possible to user Jquery ui datepicker to only show the month/year part and not the days.

I know I can get the month and year with changeMonth and changeYear options, but how can I prevent the days from showing at all?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-date-picker-to-show-month-year-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using CSS:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar { 
   display: none; 
}
```