# JqGrid, add clear button in the toolbar search column

Tags: jqgrid, datepicker

I have a JqGrid with the toolbar search enable. One of my column is a datetime column and the search field is a jquery datepicker. The problem with a datepicker is that you cannot have an empty value, but as this field is a filter it can be empty. So what id'like to do is to add a little button near the datepicker which will clear the field.
Is there a way to do this, or to be able to clear the datepicker from client side.

[image]

Here is the code for the column

```
{ name: 'Period', index: 'Period', align: 'center', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'F, Y' }, width: '70px', search: true,
                        searchoptions: {
                            dataInit: function (el) {
                                $(el).datepicker({
                                    yearRange: "-5:+1",
                                    changeMonth: true,
                                    changeYear: true,
                                    showButtonPanel: true,
                                    dateFormat: 'MM, yy',
                                    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                                        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                                        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                                        $(this).datepicker('disable');
                                        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                                        $(this).datepicker('enable');
                                        $("#jqgCompLine")[0].triggerToolbar();
                                    },
                                    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
                                        if ((datestr = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
                                            year = datestr.substring(datestr.length - 4, datestr.length);
                                            month = jQuery.inArray(datestr.substring(0, datestr.length - 6), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
                                            $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                                            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        },
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `datepicker` have no problem with empty fields. I suppose it's the problem with your customization.

I don't know which data you have as the date values in the grid. The format `'F, Y'` (and `'MM, yy'` for the datepicker) seems me a little strange because the searching will be done by full date, but you display only the mouth and year. Probably all will work correct with your data probably not.

I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchingToolbarWithDatepicker.htm) to demonstrate that searching with the datepicker. During creating of the demo I used the ['j, F, Y'](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) format (for the datepicker the ['d, MM, yy'](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) format) and found two bugs in the [parseDate](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.base.js#L84-130) method used by jqGrid internally.

The first problem are in [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.base.js#L98-105) where `date[k]` value will be correct calculated, but not assigned to `tsp.m`. One should insert in both `if` statements the assignment `tsp.m = date[k];`. So both 'F' and 'M' formats works incorrect in the current code of jqGrid. Because you use 'F' format it could be important for you.

The next problem is that the `'j'` format for the day will be processed in the wrong way. During the parsing of the date the `tsp.j` will be correctly assigned, but the `tsp.d`, which will be used in [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.base.js#L129), will be not modified and stay equal to 1. To fix the code I suggest to add the line

```
if(tsp.j !== undefined) { tsp.d = tsp.j; }
```

somewhere after the for loop. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchingToolbarWithDatepicker.htm) used the modified version [jquery.jqGrid.src-parseDate.js](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.3.1/js/jquery.jqGrid.src-parseDate.js) of the `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` of jqGrid 4.3.1.

I will report the bug and my fix to trirand later.

Comment: Hi Oleg, Thanks for your answer. For the date picker format I've got inspired by this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-date-picker-to-show-month-year-only).

Comment: @LotuX: You are welcome! I didn't say that it's wrong way. The most problem is that the input data **must** have 1 as the day. If you would have any date having not 1 as the day the user will don't see any differences and the searching will also failed. Are your problem solved now after applying the bug fix?

Comment: In fact, for the search with the datePicker, what I do is to retrieve the month and year from the datepicker and after create a select query with the entire month as the interval, this works fine. I have to admit I don't know how your datepicker can be empty because I don't know what in my datpicker forces a value.

Comment: @LotuX: I suppose that you have problems with empty cells because of your current `beforeShow` implementation. In the default implementation of datepicker there are no such problem. What is your current problem? Do you tried my suggestions? Which `datatype` you use? Do you use `loadonce: true` option?

Comment: My only problem is that I cannot make the period field empty. So I didn't tried your suggestion because if I understand well it will only help for the search ans currently the surch works fine. My datatype is json, and I don't use loadonce so I guess it's false by default. I think the main problem comes from `$(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));` which is triggered on closing the datepicker and so it cannnot be empty, but I have no idea how to by pass this.