# customise datepicker to select date from the calender that displays Month and Year only

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I read this ([jQuery UI DatePicker to show month year only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only)) and this ([How to set date of datepicker that displays Month and Year only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067866/how-to-set-date-of-datepicker-that-displays-month-and-year-only)) style of `.ui-datepicker-calendar` is set to `display:none` which is applicable for all pages , however there is single page where user should be able to choose date as well, now if we change the property of `.ui-datepicker-calendar` from `display:none` to `display:table` or `display:run-in` then user can select date as well for that page  but i am unable to change it dynamically using jquery.

I tried like this

```
$('.ui-datepicker-calendar').css('display','table');
```

Comment: Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/7755/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DatePicker creates the div with class .ui-datepicker-calendar after you set it to display:block in javascript. One option would be to change your css  class to something like:

```
.datePickerMonthAndYear .ui-datepicker-calendar{
    display:none;
}
```

and then in the beforeShow event of datepicker to add or remove .datePickerMonthAndYear .

See :
    http://jsfiddle.net/calinaadi/bmsfL4hh/

Comment: that was perfect @calinaadi