# disable days from datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is there a way to disable days from jquery UI datepicker?

I tried to use dateformat mm/yy to limit days, but my boss is still concerned that user still assume they need to choose a day

```
$("#date").datepicker({ yearRange: '1950:2015', changeYear: true, changeMonth: true });
```

I want to disable "day" and in my situation, if possible I prefer to use datepicker instead of two dropdownlists.

I saw there are some articles talking about disable specified days http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days

so I think there maybe a way to disable all days

Comment: Can you show a tiny snippet of code?  That tends to make people more interested in the problem. Also, links to existing websites or photos of the situation sometimes help.

Comment: Check this one out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-date-picker-to-show-month-year-only

Comment: If you don't want to pick a date, why are you using the datepicker? Use a pair of dropdowns to select year and month instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the `beforeShowDay` event handler on the `datepicker`'s configuration object ...

```
function restrictdays(date) {
    /* logic here */

    return [
        /* boolean indicating whether date is valid */
        isvalid,
        /* css class name */
        isvalid ? 'success' : 'failure',
        /* optional tooltip */
        isvalid ? 'good job' : 'bad job'
    ]; 
}


$(function() {
  $('#date').datepicker({
    /* ... config options ... */
    beforeShowDay: restrictdays
  });
});
```

---

[Reference](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days)

Comment: The function takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with [0] equal to true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable, [1] equal to a CSS class name(s) or '' for the default presentation, and [2] an optional popup tooltip for this date. It is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.