# jquery datepicker double use (day and month)

Tags: jquery, datepicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery UI DatePicker to show month year only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only)

i am using Jquery datepicker here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/W2Vgs/1/.

the first input is a **datepicker** while the second should be a **monthpicker**.
How can i make the second input to just show the month and year (monthpicker)?
**how can i remove the days on the second calendar**.
  is it possible to use datepicker for both option on same html page?

Comment: I am not sure what you want, can explain again please more details.

Comment: Why split something that does what you want in one interaction into two?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only

Comment: @yossi: my user should have 2 options search by date and search by month on the same page when looking for a person. that is why i need both.

Comment: @Nate: u got it, that's what i was looking for