# Datepicker with day as optional

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am looking to implement a datepicker for an expiry date. Seeing how these dates are, some have the day e.g 10/12/2013 while others have only month and year e.g Dec 2013, I would like  the user to be allowed to pick a day/month/year if the expiry is so as in the former example or month/year as in the latter.

I am using the stock jquery datepicker, I am not able to implement these options. Is it possible with this, or would i need a better plugin for such?

Thanks, regards. Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know jQuery UI datepicker does not support such sort of functionality. However there is another [jQuery plugin](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html#extend) that can be configured to allow you to choose month only (see the "Select a month only" example on the linked page).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only) question:

```
jQuery UI DatePicker to show month year only
```

maybe it is the same issue

Comment: I see, let me have a look at it , then will post back. Result

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val();
 })
```

or

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
 })
```

is this you looking ?

Comment: Thanks , this is what I might have already. Looking for a way to have dd as optional.