# Need to disable Days in Jquery-UI DatePicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm wondering if there's a method or option in JQuery datepicker to disable days in the calendar, or even a way to perhaps disable days so that choosing a month is enough to set the date.

Can't seem to find anything that does the job @ http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-navigationAsDateFormat

I have a non-paying client who requested this, so would rather keep on using the datepicker component rather than try and re-engineer an input (dual input asi t would be due to them needing MM/YY).

Any help with this could be considered my christmas and birthday gifts combined.

**Cheers in advance!**

Comment: What about using searhc? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=datepicker+disable+day+[jquery]

Comment: do you mean like in here:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only

Comment: @Sudhir. That looks pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Kept searching and getting results for removing specific dates, rather than ALL dates. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

you can refer http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-datepicker-disable-days to do 
hope it can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`beforeShowDate event`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay) of the datepicker combined with [`Date.getDay()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) to do what you want, like this:

```
​$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 1 && day != 2)];
    }
})​​​​​;​
```