# Datepicker loses date value when dateFormat doesn't include day

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two HTML input elements. The first is a read-only text input that displays the chosen month and year, and the second is a hidden input that saves the date selected:

```
<input type="text" id="MonthDisplay" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="hidden" name="Month" />
```

The goal is to store the actual date chosen in the hidden field, but to display only the month and year in the visible MonthDisplay field.

Here is code to initialize the datepicker:

```
$('#MonthDisplay')
    .datepicker({
        'dateFormat'  : 'MM yy',
        'changeMonth' : true,
        'changeYear'  : true,
        'yearRange'   : '2010:'+new Date().getFullYear(),
        'altField'    : "input[type=hidden][name=Month]",
        'altFormat'   : "m/d/yy"
    });
```

The first time the user picks the date, everything works great. The display field and the hidden field are both set correctly. But the second time the user clicks the display field, the datepicker doesn't default to the month selected. Instead, it defaults to today's month. I'm pretty sure this is happening because the control can't parse the date -- when I set the dateFormat to include the day (using the format string `"dd MM yy"`), it works great. But I don't want to include the day in the display to the user.

So my question is, how can I intercept the date that datepicker is using so on the second time through, the date remembers the previous month selected?

Or, as an alternate question, is there a way to make the datepicker or another control select only the month and year without also picking the date?

Comment: Have you ever worked around this? If yes, please post an answer and I'll give you the bounty :)

Comment: Unfortunately I was never able to get this to work. I ended up changing the user interface instead.

Comment: I'm thinking that this is going to be my fate. 2 days of open bounty and the question barely got 15 views.

Comment: @gustavohenke see makla's comment below; it might help you.

Answer (score 2):

I got the example from the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only) that @Muthukumar mentioned to "remember" the selected month (using jQuery .data()). [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mnoble01/DBpJe/1328/)

HTML:

```
<label for="startDate">Date :</label>
<input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    beforeShow: function(elem, inst) {
      var $this = $(this);
      // set the datepicker date
      $this.datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', $this.data('date'));
      // set the input date
      $this.datepicker('setDate', $this.data('date'));
    },
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
      var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
      var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
      var date = new Date(year, month, 2);
      $(this).datepicker('setDate', date)
             .data('date', date); // remember the selected date
    }
  });
});
```

However, @CharlieKilian, I couldn't get your code to work at all with the readonly input. I put your code and html (commented) into the fiddle, so you can play around with it if you want.

Comment: I've modified the fiddle to run with an readonly input and it did work :P

Comment: @gustavohenke, can you add the link to that fiddle?

Comment: I think this assumes you are just using English language version of the datepicker

Answer (score -1):

The following link should give you an idea on how to implement a datepicker to select only the month and year without picking the date.

[jQuery UI DatePicker to show month year only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only)

Comment: That example has the same problem I am having. The datepicker works, but the selected month is not remembered between drop downs.

Comment: I got the example from that SO question to "remember" the selected month -- [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mnoble01/DBpJe/1328/). However, @CharlieKilian, I couldn't get your code to work at all with the readonly input. I put your code and html (commented) into the fiddle, so you can play around with it if you want.

Comment: @makla post it as a answer and the bounty is yours :)