# JQueryUI datepicker's setDate method does not work for some date formats

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, date-format

I am using JqueryUI datepicker, and I cannot call 'setDate' method on a datepicker if I use a format like this: 'mm yy'.

See my snippet here:

```
$(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker(
        {dateFormat: 'mm yy'}
    );

    $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date(2010, 10, 1));
    var d = $("#datepicker" ).datepicker('getDate');
    alert(d); //this should alert 2010,10,1, but it is not! it alerts the current time instead
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wintlu/DmmQU/

My observation is that: 
if I use format including day part, like 'dd mm yy', then i can use setDate, but if I use format without day part, like 'mm yy', then i cannot use setDate.

My question is :
Is this a bug of datepicker?
If so, what is the walk around ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need a valid date in order to use datepicker

Comment: Do you mean 'mm yy' is an invalid format? but i only need to show year and month, do you have walk around?

Comment: I don't understand... then why would you use a datepicker if you are not using the day?

Comment: i have similar requirement as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only?lq=1  .I don't need the day, but I need month and year selection. Thank you very much