# jQuery UI Datepicker - Being able to pick day or month

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'd like to know if there is any way to be able to select a whole month in jQuery UI's `Datepicker` while still being able to select a single day.

I tried 'hacking' it by adding an `onClick` event to the title `div` after page load, but switching months seems to completely replace the div, thus losing the `onClick`.

Are there any other solutions? Or maybe an alternative which offers this option?

Comment: how do you want to get the values for whole month?

Comment: In an ISO format, such as 2013-03

Comment: sorry I cant expect what exactly you want to get, for example: whole month contains whole days? or just month? or what?

Comment: while you have tried to "hacking it", have you used a normal click-binding or a [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)-click binding?

Comment: I used a live binding. Edit: woops, meant `click` binding. I'll try `live`

Comment: Akam I'm not sure I understand your question... I just want to be able to select a whole month just as I select a single day. So the `onSelect` event would be called with '2013-03' as `dateText` parameter, for example.

Comment: as LeaenerR explained, did you tried to use dateFormat ?

Comment: Using `dateFormat` as LearneR said restricts the picking to the month, even if a day is clicked.

Comment: hah, can you please tell us exactly what do you want to be displayed and what value you want to get?

Comment: I want the regular `Datepicker` to be displayed. When I click a day, I want to receive the string corresponding to it (such as '2013-03-12'), and when I click the month in the title, I want to receive the string corresponding to it (such as '2013-03').

Comment: Jan Hommes, the solution was to use `live`'s replacement, `delegate` in order to bind the existing and future titles of the `Datepicker`, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onClick` event should be enough. You just need to use a jQuery event handler that works for dynamic links.

If < jQuery 1.7, use: [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) 
Else If >= jQuery 1.7, use: [on()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't necessarily need it to happen in one datepicker, it might be less confusing to have two of them. Use one to select the start date, and use the other one to select the end date. Once the dates are selected, you will need validation to be sure the selected end date is not before the start date (assuming you want that behavior).

Answer (score 0):

To convert jQuery date picker into mont picker will leads to you bulky code. There are many ways to do this the best one is to hide date blocks by a function over riding method. Any way you can use this plugin for month / year picker.
http://lucianocosta.info/jquery.mtz.monthpicker/

Answer (score 0):

i thing you can but Datepicker  in div id="anything"
then use live event click like this without hacking any original code

```
    $("#anything .ui-datepicker-month").live('click',function(){
        do any thing :) ;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this has already been posted here
[jQuery UI DatePicker to show month year only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only)
very similar but same effect essentially any date selected in the month displays the month only