# Get the Day and Month using Jquery

Tags: jquery, date

I need to extract the Day and month using Jquery so I'm left with 0913 . I also need to extract the date in this format too: 20130409, any suggestions on how to do so ? I know I can get the full date like this:

```
var fullDate = new Date();
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI DatePicker to show month year only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only)

Comment: So you googled and found no leads, right?

Comment: have you tried rebooting your computer?

Answer (score 0):

Get a date string from a text box using jQuery:

```
var dateParts,
    myDate;

$calendarBox = $('input[id="myCalendarTextBox"]');

$(document).ready(function () {
    $calendarBox.datepicker({
        dateFormat= 'yy/mm/dd',
        onClose: function () {
            if($calendarBox.val() != '') {
                dateParts = $calendarBox.val().split('/');
                myDate = new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1], dateParts[2]);
            }
    });
});
```