# Select year and month name in ajax calendar extender

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, calendarextender

I have a textbox and a calendar extender control with target control id property set to the  textbox. I have made the calendar select only year and month not date by using format "yyyy/MM". So every entry in the calendar will be like(2013/01,2013/02....etc).Now I have to insert the calendar value in database. I have two fields in database Year and MonthName. Now what i want is when i **Click Submit Button** I want the Year part of my textbox value to go to Year column and **MonthName** to go to MonthName column.[suppose in case of 2013/04, 2013 should go to year column and 04 should be converted to April and then go to MonthName]. How can this be done??

Answer (score 0):

in the Insert statement use LEFT(@calendar,4) for year and right(@Calendar,2) for month. Probably you will have to cast it as int depending on yout table design

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this with ajax calendar extender (version 3.5/4.0).

You should use the JQuery UI calendar, check tha answer by Ben Koehler at:
[jQuery UI DatePicker to show month year only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only)