# JQuery DatePicker with year optional

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I need to make the year optional when selecting a date in the JQuery DatePicker. Please note the word **optional**. I do not want to remove the year, I just want to make it optional.

Why? I am storing date of birth and sometimes people don't give the year they were born.

I don't think this is possible with the built in DatePicker. If not, does anyone know of another solution I could use?

Appreciate your help in advance!

Ben

Comment: I missed it.  I think this has to be handled in your js not in datepicker and also I dont find no use of DOB without year

Answer (score 0):

JQuery does not allow this sort of an option. You can anyway take a look at this [plugin](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html#extend) which allows you to select only the month. If you want to use the year as optional, you might check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change the date format however you want. This one will enter "01-27"(mm-dd) in your textbox.

```
 $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        inline: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: "mm-dd",
    });
```

Comment: Please note the word optional. I do not want to remove the year, I just want to make it optional.