# jQuery Datepicker - Display only certain months (not a range)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to force my jQuery Datepicker to allow only the months of May and October to be selected, and to increase or decrease the year according to whether the user is advancing forwards through the months or going backwards.

I'm getting closer to this goal so far with the following code, but without knowing whether the user is clicking forwards or backwards on the datepicker's month selector I can't know whether to increment or decerement the year value.

```
$("#ApplicantExpectedStartDate").datepicker({
    onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
        // Force datepicker to display only May and October

        if ((month > 5) && (month < 10)) {
            $(this).datepicker("setDate", new Date(year, 9, 1));
            $(this).datepicker("refresh");
        }

        if (month > 10) {
            $(this).datepicker("setDate", new Date(year, 4, 1));
            $(this).datepicker("refresh");
        }
    },
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    changeYear: true
});
```

Are there any events that fire immediately prior to onChangeMonthYear  that I could use in order to compare  the new date to the old one for means of comparison? Is there a much more straightforward way of doing this than I'm currently attempting?

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfejhjs8/4/

Comment: Can you please provide jsfiddle link

Comment: I think there is same problem has solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only

Answer (score 0):

It's not terribly graceful but this provides the result I want.

```
$("#ApplicantExpectedStartDate").datepicker(
                    {
                        onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {

                            // Force datepicker to display only May and October

                            // Navigating FROM May
                            if (month == 4) {
                                $(this).datepicker("setDate", new Date(year - 1, 9, 1));
                                $(this).datepicker("refresh");
                            }

                            if (month == 6) {
                                $(this).datepicker("setDate", new Date(year, 9, 1));
                                $(this).datepicker("refresh");
                            }

                            // Navigating FROM October
                            if (month == 9) {
                                $(this).datepicker("setDate", new Date(year, 4, 1));
                                $(this).datepicker("refresh");
                            }

                            if (month == 11) {
                                $(this).datepicker("setDate", new Date(year + 1, 4, 1));
                                $(this).datepicker("refresh");
                            }
                        },
                        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                        changeYear: true
                    }
            );
```