# show hide jquery datepicker calendar

Tags: jquery, datepicker

For  displaying jquery calendar with Month only I have used css as

```
   <style>
      .ui-datepicker-calendar 
      {
         display:none
      }
   </style>
```

But this CSS is applied to complete page and to other `datepicker` controls have become `monthpicker` .
How do I restrict it to only one control.

```
    <input data-val="true" id="StartMonth" name="StartMonth" type="text" value="" /> 
    $('#StartMonth').focusin(function () 
    {
        $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').css("display", "none");
        $('#StartMonth').datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1)).trigger('change');
    });
```

Comment: solution found here but created  a problem for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only?rq=1

Comment: Post your complete code please or create a problem fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little help of query u can achieve your desired result. Please follow the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/7376/

```
   $('#startDate').focusin(function(){
  $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').css("display","none");
});
```

Comment: help,  When I applied the above solution, '.ui-datepicker-calendar' gets hiiden only when I change month or year in calendar, on page load display of calendar is not hidden.

Comment: Make sure that the id which you are using in jquery is of your input field.

Comment: <input data-val="true" id="StartDate" name="StartDate" type="text" value="" /> 
          
        <input data-val="true" id="StartMonth" name="StartMonth" type="text" value="" /> 
        $('#StartMonth').focusin(function () 
        {
            $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').css("display", "none");
            $('#StartMonth').datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1)).trigger('change');
        });

Comment: Write the following code after the datepicker function call. $('#startDate').focusin(function(){
  $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').css("display","none");
});

Comment: this way could cause issue in position at which calendar shows even if we hide it. in case we are showing dropdowns of month and year

Answer (score 3):

You should add class (which hide *.ui-datepicker-calendar*) to *$(input).datepicker("widget")* within *beforeShow* datepicker option and then remove this class within *onClose* datepicker option.

```js
$('.datepicker-without-calendar').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: true,
  dateFormat: 'MM yy',
  beforeShow: function(input) {
    $(input).datepicker("widget").addClass('hide-calendar');
  },
  onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
    $(this).datepicker('widget').removeClass('hide-calendar');
  }
});

$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

```css
.hide-calendar .ui-datepicker-calendar{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input class="datepicker-without-calendar" type="text" />
<input class="datepicker" type="text" />
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question then [vote to close](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). If the question is not a duplicate then tailor the answer to this specific question.

Comment: Mind-blowing answer. I have faced the same problem for two days. But your answer solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no fiddle there . use some unique id or class of that calendar or container so that css only applied to that.

e.g

```
$(#mycalendarDiv .ui-datepicker-calendar).css("display","none");
```