# setDate in jQuery UI DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

When I use `setDate` with `dateFormat : 'yy-mm'`, jQuery UI DatePicker shows today's date and not the date specified in `setDate`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/7981/ (edited from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2209104/5568549)

But with `dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'` it shows the date specified in `setDate`.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/7982/

How to make jQuery UI DatePicker shows the date specified in `setDate` with `dateFormat : 'yy-mm'` ?

Comment: $('.date-picker').datepicker('setDate', new Date());

Comment: @WRDev what's the point of this? I want UI DatePicker to show the date specified in setDate. Not today's date.

Comment: @Curious, if you set format without day, which date will be selected in calendar? in this case text box showing the value but date-picker object set the default value from current date. Because datepicker modal is populated from that object.

Comment: *The new date may be a Date object or a string in the current date format (e.g., "01/26/2009")* - So you can make a Date Object for the month and Year you want, and pass that. But you can't pass the string. Even in the example, you have `$('.date-picker').datepicker('setDate', new Date(2000, 6));` which would work as you need.

Comment: @Twisty The problem is with dateFormat: 'yy-mm', when I click the input, UI DataPicker should show the date specified in setDate e.g.(2000, 6), but it shows today's date instead.

Comment: @Curious I see what you're observing now too. Let me do some pecking at it and see what we can do. Based on the docs, they should be exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution from [jQuery UI DatePicker to show month year only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480) 

Working Example for `dateFormat : 'yy-mm'` : http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/8057/

```
beforeShow : function(input, inst) {

 if ((datestr = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
  year = datestr.substring(0, 4);
  month = datestr.substring(datestr.length-2, datestr.length);

  $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month-1, 1));
  $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month-1, 1));

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found an article that addressed this exactly: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/show-only-month-and-year-in-jquery-ui.html

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/xwnoafxd/

Basically you just had to add `defaultDate` setting. One of those facepalm things.

```
$(function() {
  var myDate = new Date(2000, 6, 1);
  $('.date-picker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm',
    defaultDate: myDate,
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
      function isDonePressed() {
        return ($('#ui-datepicker-div').html().indexOf('ui-datepicker-close ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all ui-state-hover') > -1);
      }
      if (isDonePressed()) {
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        console.log('Done is pressed')
      }
    }
  }).datepicker("setDate", myDate);
});
```

Comment: is this how it works? when we specify a date in setDate, then defaulDate's date should be set to that date?. I mean is this what happens with dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' ? (defaultDate's date was automatically set to the same date specified in setDate?)  what I think is, UI DatePicker shows defaultDate's date (which should be set to the same date specified in setDate).. am I right?

Comment: One is an option or preference, the other is a method. `defaultDate` option sets which day is highlighted on first opening. `setDate` method sets the date for the datepicker.

Comment: but with dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',  UI DatePicker shows the date specified in setDate even though defaultDate was NOT set. How?. doesn't my previous comment make any sense to how it works?

Comment: @Curious I do not understand your question.

Comment: with dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' in this example http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/7982/ UI DatePicker shows the date specified in setDate even though defaultDate option is not set, but with dateFormat: 'yy-mm' we have to set defaultDate. Why?

Comment: @Curious I have not been able to determine why this is the case, just that it is. I also found another oddity, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/xcbs60no/ When you change the date on the 2nd field, and re-open it later, it's still using the default date.