# XDsoft jQuery datetimepicker show only month

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle, jquerydatetimepicker

I am using jQuery datetimepicker. Now I need to set only month in datetimepicker.
For that I used some code but that's not working for me.
Here is my code

```
$(function () {

    var setMinTime = "";
    $('#products_delivery').datetimepicker({
     timepicker:false,
      format: 'm',

    }); //End of collection datepicker

});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/odava7qL/)

Comment: This could get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only

Comment: @matt I used XDsoft jQuery datetimepicker when i use bootstrap date timepicker it brokes everything and showing js error. So I wanted to try with XDSoft jquery.

Comment: Hi there! Did you get this resolved?

Comment: @ZiaQamar I will check and let u know. It was long time so I forgot

Comment: has anyone solved this issue. Or anyone has any idea to achieve this