# Keeping MonthPicker Open using Jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want monthpicker to open all the time when page loads. And Change Month or Year it will Automatically Updated to lable. I can Handle Event for label updates and etc.

but I want it Open on Page is loaded.
I'm following this answer :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6013093/4952944

I have tried :- http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline But it works for date I want to make it work for Month and year picker.

I tried a demo with if I us a Division with jquery UI.

```
Date: <div id="datepicker"></div>
```

And I use Jquery like this :-

```
$( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
} );
```

It works datepicker opens Inline and open continuously.
But I want to make it work for above SO's code. I tried everything like put it on when page loads. 
I'm not sure But may be due to some change events it's not loading on page Load.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jTpUY/5/

Comment: @PradeepSingh. No it's not working. We have to open month picker on page load.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jTpUY/244/ Try this updated one

Comment: @PradeepSingh. Thank you for your efforts I got my solution.

Comment: Hey Bhavin, it would be great if you update solution here

Comment: @PradeepSingh. Ohk sure. I have given answered my own question please check it. And I will update it in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got My solution. On page Load hide the calendar view.

```
$('.ui-datepicker-calendar').css('display','none');
```

And I have change the script as per my requirement. 
But here two things to note on page load hide the calendar view. And use below script when `onChangeMonthYear` event is fired,

```
setTimeout(function() {
                   $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').hide();
});
```

**Script :-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( function() {
        $(".monthPicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'MM yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            beforeShow: true,
            onChangeMonthYear: function(dateText, inst) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                   $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').hide();
                });
                var month = $(".ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $(".ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                alert(month);
                alert(year);
            }
        });
        $(".monthPicker").focus(function () {
            $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").position({
                my: "center top",
                at: "center bottom",
                of: $(this)
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML :-**

```
<div class="monthPicker" id="month"></div>
```