# Set minimum view mode for bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am trying to open a datepicker that only allows months to be chosen, so I am trying to use the `minViewMode` option but it is not working. It allows me to view the days of each month.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        minViewMode: 1,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
});
```

This produces the below datepicker:

[image]

I am aiming for something similar to the following:

[image]

Comment: You can use [bootstrap-datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). If you want to use jQuery UI  datepicker to only select years and month see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2208480/4131048).

Comment: good solution to this duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only?noredirect=1&lq=1