# gijgo datepicker - Months and Years Only

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-4

I am using Gijgo datepicker and I need format (Jenuary 2019) without days on calendar.

[image]

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <input id="datepicker" class="form-control" name="datepicker"/>
</div>
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap',
    format: 'mmmm yyyy'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your format is not valid. in the format, for example try format: 'yyyyMM' Not sure about Gijgo datepicker but this is how you get date in month-year format, in JQuery.

or try this format:

```
dateFormat: 'MM yy'
```

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <input id="datepicker" class="form-control" name="datepicker"/>
</div>
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap',
    format: 'mmmm-yyyy'
});
```

The only mistake is not use - in between 'mmmm yyyy'