# How to implement custom date picker popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, uidatepicker

How can I implement custom date picker with  radio options with two options

- any date: user can choose any date, as a typical date picker
- select month: granular date only to year and month

like the following image

[image: d]

I think the picture is clear enough to describe the question.

thanks in advance

Comment: First thought was jqueryUI and datepicker solution.  But then I see you want to allow user to pick only Month and Year and be done.  I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208480/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-month-year-only 
And there's a fiddle you can take a look at to see if that is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/7755/

Comment: @raddevus, thanks for your attention. but as you see in the image, it has two options, one make it typically date picket and the second one only month and date.